# Как настроить Port Security на коммутаторе QSW-3310?

Tags: безопасность, port

Коллеги! У меня возникла неотложная задача - нужно настроить Port Security на коммутаторе QSW-3310. Можете подсказать, как правильно выполнить эту процедуру на этой линейке? Какие параметры и шаги следует учесть для обеспечения безопасности сети и предотвращения несанкционированного доступа к портам? Буду признателен !

Answer (score 0):

Настройка **Port Security** на коммутаторе QSW-3310 ( аналогична 3300/3750-28TX)
Функция Port Security представляет собой привязку безопасных MAC-адресов к заданному порту. Пакеты, с подходящим MAC-адресом источника пересылаются нормально, а все прочие - блокируются.

**Безопасные MAC-адреса**

- Коммутатор поддерживает такие типы безопасных MAC-адресов:

**Статические MAC-адреса:**

- задаются статически в режиме настройки интерфейса;
- добавляются в текущую конфигурацию коммутатора и, после перезагрузки коммутатора, не удаляются.

**Динамические MAC-адреса:**

- динамически выучиваются;
- удаляются при перезагрузке коммутатора.

**Sticky MAC-адреса:**

- могут быть статически настроены или динамически выучены;
- добавляются в текущую конфигурацию коммутатора. Если эти адреса сохранены в конфигурационном файле, после перезагрузки коммутатора, их не надо заново перенастраивать.

**Режимы реагирования на нарушения безопасности**

Нарушением безопасности для port security считаются ситуации:

- максимальное количество безопасных MAC-адресов было добавлено в таблицу адресов и хост, чей MAC-адрес не записан в таблице адресов пытается получить доступ через интерфейс;
- адрес, выученный или настроенный как безопасный на одном интерфейсе, появился на другом безопасном интерфейсе в том же VLAN'е.

**На интерфейсе могут быть настроены режимы реагирования на нарушения безопасности:**

**Protect (по умолчанию)** — когда количество безопасных MAC-адресов достигает максимального ограничения, настроенного на порту, пакеты с неизвестным MAC-адресом отправителя отбрасываются до тех пор, пока не будет удалено достаточное количество безопасных MAC-адресов, чтобы их количество было меньше максимального значения, или увеличено максимальное количество разрешенных адресов. Оповещения о нарушении безопасности нет.

**Restrict** — когда количество безопасных MAC-адресов достигает максимального ограничения, настроенного на порту, пакеты с неизвестным MAC-адресом отправителя отбрасываются до тех пор, пока не будет удалено достаточное количество безопасных MAC-адресов, чтобы их количество было меньше максимального значения, или увеличено максимальное количество разрешенных адресов. В этом режиме при нарушении безопасности отправляется оповещение — отправляется SNMP trap и сообщение syslog.

**Shutdown** — нарушение безопасности приводит к тому, что интерфейс переводится в состояние error-disabled и немедленно отключается, а также выключается светодиодный индикатор порта. Отправляется SNMP trap и сообщение syslog.

Чтобы интерфейс вывести из состояния error-disabled, необходимо в настройках интерфейса его выключить и включить либо в глобальной конфигурации указать условие, при котором это произойдет автоматически, например по времени:

QSW-3310(config)#errdisable recovery cause port-security
QSW-3310(config)#errdisable recovery interval 1800

Режим protect не рекомендуется настраивать для транка. Этот режим выключает запоминание адресов, когда какой-либо VLAN достигает максимума адресов, даже если порт не достиг максимального ограничения.

**Примеры конфигурации**

Конфигурация для Protect со статическими МАС-адресами:

```
QSW-3310#configure terminal
     QSW-3310(config)#port-security
     QSW-3310(config)#interface 1/0/1
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#switchport access vlan 10
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security violation protect
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security max-dynamic 0
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security max-static 3
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security mac-address 00:00:00:00:14:03 10
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security mac-address 00:00:00:00:14:04 10
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security mac-address 00:00:00:00:14:05 10
```

Конфигурация для Restrict с динамическими МАС-адресами:

```
QSW-3310#configure terminal
     QSW-3310(config)#port-security
     QSW-3310(config)#interface 1/0/1
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#switchport access vlan 10
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security violation restrict
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security max-dynamic 3
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security max-static 0
```

Конфигурация для Shutdown с sticky МАС-адресами:

```
QSW-3310#configure terminal
     QSW-3310(config)#port-security
     QSW-3310(config)#errdisable recovery cause port-security
     QSW-3310(config)#errdisable recovery interval 1800
     QSW-3310(config)#interface 1/0/1
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#switchport access vlan 10
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security violation shutdown
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security max-dynamic 0
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security max-static 3
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#snmp-server enable traps violation
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security mac-address sticky
```

Конфигурация для Shutdown с настройкой SNMP сервера и SNMP trap:

```
QSW-3310(config)#snmp-server enable
     QSW-3310(config)#snmp-server community "RW" rw
     QSW-3310(config)#snmp-server host 192.168.2.5 traps version 2 "RW"
     QSW-3310(config)#port-security
     QSW-3310(config)#errdisable recovery interval 1800
     QSW-3310(config)#interface 1/0/1
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#switchport access vlan 10
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security violation shutdown
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security max-dynamic 0
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security max-static 5
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#snmp-server enable traps violation
     QSW-3310 (Interface 1/0/1)#port-security mac-address sticky
```

Актуальная информация по настройке расположена [на сайте](https://www.qtech.ru/education/articles/nastroyka-port-security-na-kommutatore-qsw-3310-3300-3750-28tx/)